# I am trying to replace 'text domain' in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to find and replace Text Domain in WordPress theme or plugin using Notepad++?

I want to replace this

```
__('Text', 'text-domain'),
esc_html__('text', "text-domain"),
```

to

```
__('Text', 'my-text-domain'),
esc_html__('text', "my-text-domain"),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F>Replace if that is what you are looking for